# Spring Boot soap client auto retry

Tags: spring-boot, jax-ws, soap-client

I have a Microservice written in Spring Boot.

```
<!-- SOAP consumer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But sometime when make a Soap call to other server, it automaticly make 2 requests.

```
MyService service = new
            MyService();
    MyPortType portType = service
            .getPort();
    ((BindingProvider) portType).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, user);
    ((BindingProvider) portType).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, pass);
    ((BindingProvider) portType).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
            endpoint);
    return portType.makeSoapCall(input);
```

In my app, only 1 request log and 1 response log. But in server, this is 2.
I was try with VM argument "-Dsun.net.http.retryPost=false -Dhttp.retryPost=false" but no luck.

So, Anyone can give me a help?
Thank you!

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: I am still watching, I am not sure the problem is fixed or not. Are you have the same problem ?

Comment: yes, I was. I also added given 2 above argument and seems fixed. We are also watching. I ll let you know if there ll be any news.